# Evaluating an integral using logarithms.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral:

$$ \int \frac{1}{x\log_3 x} dx $$

I tried to change it to this form :

$$ \int \frac{\ln 3}{x\ln x} dx $$

But i couldn't continue. How could i arrive to this form $ \dfrac{D(f(x))}{f(x)} $

Comment: Let $u=\ln x$. Or in your notation, let $f(x)=\ln x$.

Comment: So let $ u = ln x  \;and\; x = e^u \;and\; dx = du\;x$ then $ \int \frac{ln3}{u} du $ So far is that right ? I can't continue.

Comment: So we get $(\ln 3)(\ln(|u|))+C$, now put $\ln x$ where you see $u$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Tennisman : Don't write x\;ln\;x.  Just write x \ln x, with a backslash.  The backslash not only prevents italicization but also provides proper spacing, so that what you see is $x\ln x$, not $x ln x$ or $x\;ln\;x$.  That is standard usage.  I changed it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the info :)

Comment: There is by now an answer, and you fully know how to do the problem, so there is no need of more.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{1}{x\log_3x}dx$$$$=\int \frac{\ln3}{x \ln x}dx.$$Now let $\ln x=u \implies\frac{dx}{x}=du$.Therefore   $I=\ln3 \int \frac{1}{u}du=\ln3(\ln u+c)=\ln3\ln(\ln x)+c'.$ Where $c'=c\ln3$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(\ln 3)\int \frac{1}{\ln x} \Big(\frac{dx}{x}\Big) = (\ln 3) \int \frac 1 u \, du. 
$$